# Should we clarify that game-specific tags are for mods?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have several game-specific tags on the site, such as [skyrim](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim), [world-of-warcraft](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) and [minecraft](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) because modding questions for games are considered on-topic here.

We also have [mods](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods), which serves as identifying questions about modding that are not game-specific or for games too unpopular to get game-specific tags on their own.

This means that *some* of these questions are "double-tagged" with [mods](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) and the game-specific tag, while others are tagged with one or the other.

Should we do anything about this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I propose that we rename game-specific tags to have a "-modding" suffix, so we'd have `skyrim-modding` and the like. We should rename `mods` to `modding` for uniformity, but otherwise leave it alone because it serves a useful purpose.

When we find questions that are double-tagged, we should remove the less-relevant tag.

Comment: Please remember that comments aren't for extended discussion, especially of tangential issues to the post. One can make another meta thread or use the [chat] if necessary.