# Do we need two tags for Skyrim related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two tags for Skyrim:

- 19 questions with [skyrim-creation-kit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-creation-kit)
- 24 questions with [skyrim-modding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-modding)
- 15 questions with both

According to the [Creation Kit Wiki](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Main_Page),

> [...]  everything you need to use the Creation Kit and make mods for The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim.

This tells me that if one wants to make a mod for Skyrim, they'll need the Creation Kit.

Since I have not played the game, I'm asking:

Do we really need both of these tags, or one would be enough, given the scope of the topic (preferably [skyrim-modding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-modding) to be consistent with the [others](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/should-we-clarify-that-game-specific-tags-are-for-mods))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we need both, mainly for the reasons you state in the question. [skyrim-modding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-modding) seems like the one we should keep.

Comment: I wonder about synonyms for this though. Creation Kit works for both fallout 4 and skyrim. But I agree skyrim-creation-kit makes more sense as skyrim-modding.